# Odd tap and hold in SpriteKit behavior

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

Okay, here's a tricky one. I want informative alert boxes to appear when the user taps and holds on the screen.

Here's the code I use to do this (in Objective-C SpriteKit):

In my `touchesBegan:withEvent:` method, I have this:

```
tapBegin = [NSDate date];
```

Guessing that makes an `NSDate` object with the current date and time (the Objective-C and Apple equivalent to `DateTime date = Now`).

In my `touchesEnded:withEvent:` method, I have this:

```
NSDate *endTap = [NSDate date];
NSDateComponents *comps = [[NSCalendar calendarWithIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian] components:NSCalendarUnitSecond fromDate:tapBegin toDate:endTap options:0];
if (comps.second >= 1) {
     // tap and hold event
} else {
     // normal tap event
}
```

The result should be this: if a user taps and holds something for more than one second, the `if` statement should be `true`, and if not, then it should be `false`.

The actual result has odd behavior: if a user tries to tap on something, they randomly get the tap and hold event. How do I fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the difference between two dates then you should instead be using `timeIntervalSinceDate:`
I would change the `touchesEnded:withEvent:` to the following:

```
NSDate *endTap = [NSDate date];
NSTimeInterval diff = [tapBegin timeIntervalSinceDate:endTap];
NSTimeInterval threshold = 1.0;
if (diff >= threshold) {
    // tap and hold event
} else {
    // normal tap event
}
```